# Sólo me reconoce el primer Bean en mi fichero XML Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE_USER' in value "${BASE_USER}"

Tags: java, xml, spring

Estoy utilizando `application.properties` con beans para un proyecto, hasta ahora tenía diferentes propiedades definidas en el fichero de propiedades que se utilizaban en un bean el cual funcionaba correctamente.

Mi problema surge cuando he querido añadir nuevas propiedades al fichero de propiedades y usarlas como propiedades de un nuevo bean, si útilizo alguna de las propiedades anteriores en el nuevo bean, me las recoge correctamente y no me da error, sin embargo si intento utilizar alguna de las propiedades nuevas en el bean, me sale el siguiente error:

```
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:225)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'propiedadesDAO' defined in file [C:\altemista-cloudfwk\workspace\autenticared\autenticared-red-core\target\classes\spring\autenticared-red-core.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE_USER' in value "${BASE_USER}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE_USER' in value "${BASE_USER}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:182)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at es.red.es.autenticared.microservice.MicroserviceApplication.main(MicroserviceApplication.java:11)
```

Este es el fichero xml.

````
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Scans for the red business module implementation declared via annotations 
        (i.e.: "@Service" annotated classes) -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="es.red.es.autenticared.red.service" />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="es.red.es.autenticared.red.autenticared.gestion.dao" />
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:spring/application.properties" />


    <bean id="propiedadesLdap"
        class="es.red.es.autenticared.red.model.PropiedadesConexion">

        <property name="ldapHost" value="${LDAP_HOST}">
        </property>
        <property name="ldapPort" value="${LDAP_PORT}">
        </property>
        <property name="ldapPass" value="${LDAP_PASS_AUTH}">
        </property>
        <property name="ldapBaseDomain" value="${LDAP_DOMINIO_BASE}">
        </property>
        <property name="ldapConexionAuth"
            value="${LDAP_CONEXION_AUTH}">
        </property>
        <property name="ldapDominioBusqueda"
            value="${LDAP_DOMINIO_BUSQUEDA}">
        </property>
        <property name="ldapDominioUsuario"
            value="${LDAP_USUARIO_DOMAIN}">
        </property>

    </bean>
    

        
    <bean id="propiedadesDAO" 
        class="es.red.es.autenticared.red.model.PropiedadesBase">
    
    <property name="userBase" value="${BASE_USER}"> </property>
    <property name="pass" value="${PASS}"></property>
    <property name="port" value="${PORT}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${URL}"></property>
    <property name="db" value="${DB}"></property>
    <property name="driver" value="${DRIVER}"></property>
    <property name="tecnologia" value="${TECNOLOGIA}"></property>


    
    
    </bean>
</beans>```


El fichero de propiedades tienen los nombres tal cual están en el xml, pero sólo me reconoce las propiedades del primer bean, ninguna de las del segundo.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias de antemano.
````

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. Lee [ask]: para mejor legibilidad, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código _como texto, con formato_. Puedes darle formato con el botón que indica `{}`, o entre `~~~`.

Answer (score 0):

al final aunque estaba haciendo referencia al fichero application.properties que se encontraba en el classpath, las propiedades las estaba cogiendo del application.properties del proyecto .env.

No me queda muy claro por qué pasa esto pero bueno. Solucionado.